# I cannot click on the properties which has no ID's defined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chai

```html
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

let browser1;
let directorName;
let writerName;
let starNames;
let page;

before(async () => {
  browser1 = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--window-size=1920,1080"],
  });
  page = await browser1.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
  });
});

describe("IMDB Senarios", () => {
  it("Go to https://www.imdb.com/", async () => {
    await page.goto("https://www.imdb.com/", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    });
  });

  it("Click on the Menu button", async () => {
    await page.click("#imdbHeader-navDrawerOpen--desktop");
  });

  it("Click on the Oscars button", async () => {
    /*const oscarButton = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Oscars')]");
    await oscarButton.click();*/
    await page.click(".ipc-list-item__text :text('Oscars')");
  });

  it("Select 1929 value", async () => {
    await page.click("a[text=1929]");
  });

  it("Select The Circus (Charles Chaplin)", async () => {
    await page.click("img[title=The Circus]");
  });

  it("Save Director, Writer and Stars information of the movie", async () => {
    let el = document.querySelector("span[text=Director]/parent/div/ul/li/a");
    directorName = el.innerText;
    el = document.querySelector("span[text=Writer]/parent/div/ul/li/a");
    writerName = el.innerText;
    el = document.querySelector("a[text=Stars]/parent/div/ul");
    starNames = el.innerText;
    done();
  });

  it("Click on the IMDb button", async () => {
    await page.click("#home_img_holder");
    done();
  });

  it("Search The Circus", async () => {
    await page.type("input[name=q]", "The Circus");
  });

  it("Click on the The Circus", async () => {
    await page.type("div[text=The Circus]");
    done();
  });

  it("Check wheter Director, Writer and Stars information of the movie", async () => {
    let el = document.querySelector("span[text=Director]/parent/div/ul/li/a");
    chai.end(() => {
      el.innerText.should.equal(directorName);
    });
    el = document.querySelector("span[text=Writer]/parent/div/ul/li/a");
    chai.end(() => {
      el.innerText.should.equal(writerName);
    });
    el = document.querySelector("a[text=Stars]/parent/div/ul");
    chai.end(() => {
      el.innerText.should.equal(starNames);
    });
    done();
  });

  it("Click on the Photo Gallery", async () => {
    await page.type("h3[text=Photos]");
  });
});
```

I am trying to test the IMDb charlie chaplin's The circus page. I could easily get puppeteer click on the properties with defined ID's. However, some properties which has no ID's gave me hard time. I could not click on them. I tried several different methods such as xpath, css and etc. Please help me I am new to puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

open the DevTools (ctrl + shift + I), go to the "inspector" tab, find the element you want to query, right click it and select Copy -> Copy Selector. It'll give you the query string you can use in page.click() to click on your element of choice.
[image: like this]

you can read about CSS Selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)